# Swift - Add items to array from API Call

Tags: ios, swift

I have this API call like so:

```
var items = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let url = NSURL(string: "API.php")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
            println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        }

        task.resume()

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

What I am trying to do is add each item to the array items, I have tried the following:

`items += [NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))` but that didnt work, does anyone know how to do this ? I am new to swift as of this morning.

When i say it didn't work, it just took my ajax data and has it as one string.

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work" ?

Comment: Try items = [String?]()

Answer (score 0):

First: Avoid untyped empty array literals, because the language isn't likely to give you what you want. Last time I tried something like `var items = []`, it gave me an NSArray. The alternative would be an array of Any--neither of these are desirable when you have generic types.

My preference is to use a typed array initializer for an empty array, like so:

```
var items = [String]()
```

In your data task callback, go ahead and `.append()` the data to the array AFTER you've checked whether an error is present.

Another thing: if this is going to be used to populate a table view, it's not enough to just add the item to the array. You will need to use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.tableView.reloadData() }`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

> var items = []

defines an immutable `NSArray` instance.
You should define it as

```
var items = [NSString]()
if let item = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
    items.append(item) //or items += [item]
}
```

Comment: But how would I convert it to `[]` I need it for my TableViewController

Comment: I can guarantee that your TableViewController doesn't need an empty, immutable NSArray instance. items in this example is a mutable array of strings, which is something that would actually work for what you're probably trying to do.

Comment: @user979331 You don't have to do that. It can be the datasource of TableViewController. If you want to convert, use the `as` to downcast.  `var newItems = items as [Your Type]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1) Init MutableArray for item :

```
let home_image:NSMutableArray=NSMutableArray()
let home_title:NSMutableArray=NSMutableArray()
let home_pdf:NSMutableArray=NSMutableArray()
let home_sqft:NSMutableArray=NSMutableArray()
let home_savings:NSMutableArray=NSMutableArray()
let home_price:NSMutableArray=NSMutableArray()`
```

2) Get your Item data from your API response(result) and add item to mutableArray

```
var temp: NSString = data.valueForKey("home_image") as! NSString!
self.home_image.addObject(temp)

temp = data.valueForKey("home_title") as! NSString!
self.home_title.addObject(temp)

temp = data.valueForKey("home_pdf") as! NSString!
self.home_pdf.addObject(temp)

temp = data.valueForKey("home_sqft") as! NSString!
self.home_sqft.addObject(temp)

temp = data.valueForKey("home_savings") as! NSString!
self.home_savings.addObject(temp)

temp = data.valueForKey("home_price") as! NSString!
self.home_title.addObject(temp)
```